# Mapping / Join with @Transient entity field HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hql

I have these entities:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "my_table")
  public class MyTable implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "RECORD_ID")
     private Long recordId;

     @Column(name = "CNAME")
     private String changeName;

     @Transient
     MyTableTwo tableTwo;

     //getters and setters
 }
```

MyTableTwo entity:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "my_table_two")
  public class MyTableTwo implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "REC_ID")
     private Long recId;

     @Column(name = "CNAME")
     private String changeName;

     @Column(name = "CVAL")
     private String changeValue;

     //getters and setters
 }
```

I want to get `my_table.record_id`. 'my_table.cname', 'my_table_two.cval' in a result.
How to write a query on these two entities?

Can we write a join query with first entity and @transient entity field of 2nd entity?

I need to write HQL

Comment: `MyTable` doesn't have a relationship to `MyTableTwo` since that field is `@Transient`

Comment: As these tables do not share a relationship, you can do a cross join using Hibernate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So we cannot use the 2nd one in Join?

Comment: @Ean, Can you show an example?

Comment: @kevin I don't think so, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cross join like

```
select a,b from MyTable a,MyTableTwo b where a.prop1 = b.prop2
```

Comment: Is it possible with @Transient field inside A?